# Average update size on Debian

Tags: debian, upgrade, software-updates

I want to set up a `NAT` gateway on `AWS` to put some private `EC2` instances behind them.

Since `NAT` gateway [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/) also depends on

> Price per GB data processed

I was wandering whether there is an estimate on the average size of the updates a `debian` os receives per month so as to be as accurate as possible on my cost projections.

Traffic through `NAT` gateways will for the machines to be able to receive updates (not expecting any other significant incoming traffic to them)

Comment: This is going to depend quite a lot on what you've got installed.

Comment: These will be `kubernetes` nodes actually

Answer (score 3):

Plan your setup well for minimising install/updates traffic.

Several AWS images and distributions can be updated internally from AWS servers, I believe. Internal traffic won't be charged.

If it is not the case, plan and configure an [APT proxy](https://wiki.debian.org/AptCacherNg), and configure the APT proxy to be used by all your Debian servers.

In that way, the APT proxy only fetches the updates once, when any of the machines request the packages, and all your Debian servers get/share the packages from it.

As for hard data, I would go to the Debian security repository and do a rough math average. As @Michael Homer comments, it depends on what packages you have installed; APT proxy/security updates will only fetch updates to the installed packages.

I would not worry too much about the traffic of the security updates.